# Shorthand for C++ nested types from reference-to-T

Tags: c++, c++17

Given a nested type name such as

```
struct mytype
{
  using mynestedtype = int;
};

mytype value;
mytype& ref2value = value;
```

Is there a convenient notation to obtain `mytype::mynestedtype` inside a generic lambda, that is easier than the following?

```
auto mylambda = [](auto& x){
  typename std::remove_reference<decltype(x)>::type::mynestedtype y;
  //...
}


mylambda(ref2value);
```

I wish I could do `x::mynestedtype`, or at least `decltype(x)::mynestedtype`, but neither is valid c++.

Comment: C++20 solution: `[]<class T>(T & t) { auto y = T::mynestedtype(); }`

Comment: Sadly, I'm stuck on 17 for the moment, but thank you.

Comment: `typename std::decay_t<decltype(x)>::mynestedtype y;` I don't think there is a shorter C++17 solution.